# Sufficient statistic and information

Tags: statistics

I have seen it claimed (for instance, [here](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/print/book/export/html/244)) that sufficient statistics are those that "capture all the information" available about an underlying parameter. A related claim is that once the statistic is known, no other function of the observations will give any additional information about the value of the parameter.

Then the formal definition is sometimes given as requiring only that the conditional distribution of the observations, given the statistic, does not depend on the underlying parameter. What is not clear to me is that the "information" version of the definition is equivalent to the "independence" version of the definition. The explanations I have looked at seem to consider this an obvious point, but as a non-statistician, I am having trouble.

So here is the question: What is the connection between these two notions of sufficiency?

Either rigorous and non-rigorous answers would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: In my class on algebraic statistics,i consider a sufficient statistic as the collection of values defining the likelihood fct.

Comment: Interesting. That seems like a nice way to encapsulate the "information" definition. Any idea how to connect that to the "independence" version?